# Upload file to http using spring in a standalone application

Tags: java, spring, apache, http, file-upload

I am working at a standalone application in java. I am using Spring with Apache Server and i want to upload a file to server. My problem is that i received a lot of deprecated warnings on my client-side. Could someone give me some hints?

Client-side:

```
public void addCourse(ActionEvent e) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        File file=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this.mainApp.getCurrentStage());
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/ASCourses/filter/upload");


        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");
        mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);


        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
          System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
          resEntity.consumeContent();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
      }
```

Server-Side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload( 
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
            String name = "test11";
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = 
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

Also i want to ask you if it is any other method to upload file. Remember, i am using a standalone application, not web.
Thank you.